# disappearing scroll bar on html

Tags: html, css

all...see the code below...it almost works the way I want.  Problem is there are no scroll bars.  I can fix it two ways:

1) remove the !doctype... declaration at the top.  Then it works great, but I imagine I am creating grief for myself.
2) change the height from a relative amount (%) to a fixed amount (px).  Any height i put in causes the scroll bars to come back...but then my view is a fixed size and doesn't change on different window sizes.  Thoughts?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #Content {
            overflow: auto;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Content">
        Yesterday<br />Today<br />Tomorrow<br />1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />31<br />32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38<br />39<br />40<br />41<br />42<br />43<br />44<br />45<br />46<br />47<br />48<br />49<br />
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
        Yesterday<br />Today<br />Tomorrow<br />1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />31<br />32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38<br />39<br />40<br />41<br />42<br />43<br />44<br />45<br />46<br />47<br />48<br />49<br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want the scrollbars? Inside the #content divs?

Comment: Just FYI, an `id` needs to be unique. So your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @putvande:it doesn't matter in this case, CSS apply styles to both ID elements. Problem would be just with JavaScript which takes the first one element.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar is on `body` and you set `overflow: hidden;`. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%;` on `#content` only works if the parent element has a set height, which `<body>` initially does not. Set the height of the `<body>`, and it's parent, `<html>` to 100% if you want it to work:

```
 body,html {
     height:100%;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c0pLst0n/)

Also, as @putvande pointed out, id's must be unique. Use a class instead: `<div class="Content">`

Comment: Down voters care to comment? If you see something wrong with my answer, please tell me about it.

Comment: Did you even try this? This still gets rid of the scrollbar. http://jsfiddle.net/cno09mL7/

Comment: @putvande did you try it? if `#content` is less more then the height of the window, it has scroll bars, which i assumed the OP wants.

Comment: Hmm yeah fair enough, if OP wants it on the content div.

Comment: @putvande he means `#content` "2) change the height from a relative amount (%) to a fixed amount (px)."

Answer (score 0):

you have `overflow-hidden` on the body remove it and it will be fine.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Content {
            overflow: auto;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Content">
        Yesterday<br />Today<br />Tomorrow<br />1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />31<br />32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38<br />39<br />40<br />41<br />42<br />43<br />44<br />45<br />46<br />47<br />48<br />49<br />
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
        Yesterday<br />Today<br />Tomorrow<br />1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />31<br />32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38<br />39<br />40<br />41<br />42<br />43<br />44<br />45<br />46<br />47<br />48<br />49<br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```